# Receiving "expected unqualified-id" when creating a function

Tags: c++, vector, lexer

Bear with me here, as I'm coming from a pure Java/Python background and have about a 10% knowledge in the **basics** of C++.

I'm defining a tokenising class for a Lexer, and have already run into a problem, with the Eclipse compiler throwing:

> expected unqualified-id

Thats it. No information whatsoever. This same error pops up no matter what I name my function. I think it may have to do with the way I'm using `vector<string> tokenise` but I have no idea...

I setup my `h` and `cpp` file like so:

**lexer.h**

```
#ifndef LEX_LEXER_H_
#define LEX_LEXER_H_

#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct token;

vector<token> tokenise(vector<string> data);

#endif /* LEX_LEXER_H_ */
```

**lexer.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum token_type {
    // Operations.
    ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, MOD,
    // Bitwise operations.
    BITL, BITR,
    // Keywords.
    DEFINE,
    // Primitives.
    INT, FLOAT, CHAR, STRING, BOOL
};

struct token {
    token_type type;
    string data;
};

vector<token> tokenise(vector<string> data) { // <<< throwing the error
    vector<token> tokens;
    for (string s : data) {
        for (char& c : s) {
            cout << c << endl;
        }
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Do not pollute your global namespace with `using namespace std;` in a header file

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thankyou for the tip! May I ask why **not**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3953764

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Ah, thanks. Would this also be a bad idea in the source file too?

Comment: In general yes, in practice not really

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Alright. Thankyou for the information. Anything helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `lexer.h` in `lexer.cpp`

Comment: I just can't believe it was that simple. Thankyou very much.